# Html footer not appearing on bottom of page in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Currently this footer works for both Chrome and IE however for some reason it does not work with Firefox.

```
div.footer{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}

.footer div{
    padding: 5px 0px;
}

.footer a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is being used to format a footer in ruby that is yielding to page content. For some reason Firefox has it right at the bottom of the content pane rather then the bottom of the screen. This may be a problem with the yield function as it changes location when the bottom or position styles are removed, however it no longer works appropriately in other browsers.

Here is an example of what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/3dme9em8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error to be in my container for the ruby elements

```
min-height: 100%;
```

was not using the full page height in Firefox